# Creating thumbnails in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning!

When importing WP entries, there was a problem with creating thumbnails for photos. I use the function `wp_generate_attachment_metadata`, but at some point the script is interrupted (it has time to create thumbnails for several dozen photos), no errors are returned. Checked the memory -  everything is fine, and timouts are exposed. So many days I fight, but still can't understand what the problem is.

Code:

```
foreach ($value['fotos'] as $i => $val) {

    $img       = str_replace('//', 'http://', $val['max']);
    $img_name  = $img_folder.basename($img);
    $img_title = basename($img);
    $attach_id = $id.'10'.$i;               

    if (!file_exists($img_name)) {
        downloadFile($img, $img_name);
    }

    $filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($img_name), null);
    $post_img = array(
        'import_id'      => $attach_id,
        'post_author'    => 1,
        'post_parent'    => $id,
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'].'/property_images/'.$id.'/'.basename($img_name),
        'post_name'      => mb_strtolower($img_title),
        'post_title'     => $img_title,
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type']
    );

    if ($wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $attach_id))) {

        unset($post_img['import_id']);
        $post_img['ID'] = $attach_id;
        wp_update_post($post_img);

    } else {
        wp_insert_post($post_img);
    }

    if ( !is_wp_error($attach_id) ) {
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $img_name));
    }

    if ($i == 0) {
        update_metadata('post', $id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    }

    update_metadata('post', $attach_id, '_wp_attached_file', $img_name);

}
```